# How to run your java app using Sudo on MAC OS X

Tags: java, macos, admin

Today i need your help :x I've seen a lot of answer but there are never full..
I want to launch my java app by another with

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("my command");
```

On the MAC OS X. Then i found that command:

```
#!/bin/sh
osascript -e "do shell script \"$*\" with administrator privileges"
```

What have i to change in this script to run my app like on linux which is:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("gksudo java -jar myjar");
```

I would like to have

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("osascript -e \"do shell script \\"$*\\" with administrator privileges");
```

but is it possible ? thanks for you anwser :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call the osascriptWrapper.sh script from Java:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/path/to/osascriptWrapper.sh myjar.jar");
```

Define osascriptWrapper.sh as:

```
#!/bin/bash

osascript -e "do shell script \"/path2/to2/runJar.sh $*\" with administrator privileges"
```

And runJar.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

java -jar $*
```

Comment: hi, does it give admin rights to the current Runtime ?

Comment: It gives admin rights only within the current invocation.  So, calling osascriptWrapper.sh a second time also requires authentication.

Comment: it isn't what i want. I want to run my java application with root access. I want to run a .jar with admin privileges. To do this, i want to use another java application which starts the second

Comment: Just tried calling Runtime.getRuntime().exec("id") after calling Runtime.getRuntime().exec("osascriptWrapper.sh ..."), and it does not have admin privileges.  This confirms that you'll have to authenticate again with osascriptWrapper.sh to obtain admin rights again.

Comment: But i want admin privileges all times, cause it is an installer which needs to access to specific folders, i want to bypass security exceptions, you know what i mind ?

Comment: You can define "realScript.sh" to simply call  java -jar {jarFilenameToRunAsRoot}.  This will give you root throughout the runtime of the 2nd java app.

Comment: i want to write that since the begin. Can you edit your anwser & do the script, i have no idea to how to write it, please :)

Comment: do you have any contact ? I would like to speak with you, do you have skype ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68004/discussion-between-romain-p-and-danny-daglas).

Answer (score 0):

You can use sudo on mac the same way you do on linux

Comment: and inftead to say that, write a shell script

Comment: @Romain-p just use `sudo`. I am sure you can figure out yourself how to write the shell script :) I believe in you. "Same way as on linux" should be enough instruction, provided, you already know how to do it on linux :)

Comment: maybe "osascript -e \"do shell script \\\"java -jar %s\\\" with administrator privileges\""

Comment: `sudo java -jar myjar`